# Rosout topic, non-string messages

Tags: ros, rosbag, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I read I understand that all topics messages are displayed in rosout topic. But as I see the messages that are different than a simple string aren't displayed, isn't it?

So what can I do if I want to show all the messages from all topics?. Is there a log file? or can I change the rosout configuration?. Perhaps the unique method is to subscribe to every topic?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10220/rosout-topic,-non-string-messages/) by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosout does not display all topics!
It displays information send from programs via ROS_INFO/ROS_WARN, etc.

You can look at any message via: `rostopic echo <topic>`.
And yes, there are logging facilities. Look for rosrecord and rosbag.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2